# LINQ query using StartsWith and Contains to limit the results for an autocomplete field

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc

As a source for a jquery-ui autocomplete field, I've written this action:

```
public ActionResult Autocomplete(string term)
{
    List<Relation> relations =
        db.Relation
            .Where(l => l.AdministrationId == Helpers.Session.AdministrationId &&
                        l.IsSupplier == true)
            .ToList();

    term = term.ToLowerInvariant();

    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    foreach (Relation r in relations) {
        string name = r.Name.ToLowerInvariant();

        if (name.StartsWith(term) || name.Contains(term)) {
            results.Add(name);
        }
    }

    results = results.OrderBy(l => l).Take(5).ToList();

    return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Since this is very verbose and probably far from optimized, I'd like to know what I can improve.

I've tried to put it all in a single LINQ query, like the code below. However, LINQ will try to interpret everything as extension methods and throw an error (`ToLowerInvariant()` and `StartsWith()`).

```
term = term.ToLowerInvariant();

IEnumerable<string> suppliers =
    db.Relations
        .Where(l => l.AdministrationId == Helpers.Session.AdministrationId &&
                    l.IsSupplier== true &&
                    (l.Name.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith(term) ||
                     l.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(term)))
        .Select(l => l.Name)
        .OrderBy(l => l)
        .Take(5);
```

What I'm looking for is a way to improve the first code snippet. It looks very verbose now and I'm pretty sure it's far from optimized when handling a lot of requests and when I have lots of rows in my database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Naming**
Instead of `term` maybe `searchTerm` would be better. As in your second example you name the `IEnumerable<>` variable `suppliers`, your method would be better named as `AutocompleteSuppliers`.

**Review**

A `Boolean` variable can be evaluated just by using the variable, so `&& l.IsSupplier == true` can be replaced by `&& l.IsSupplier`. As an evaluation of an boolean is faster as the comparing of an int (assuming `AdministrationId`  is an int) we change the order of the `where` condition like

```
List<Relation> relations =
    db.Relation
        .Where(l => l.IsSupplier &&
               l.AdministrationId == Helpers.Session.AdministrationId)
```

Inside the `foreach` loop you are first checking if the `Relation.Name` is starting with `term` and if not, you are checking if `term` is contained inside `Relation.Name`. This will be faster if `term` is often the starting of the name, but will be slower if it is contained as of the double check.
So let us just remove the `StartsWith()`.

Your combination of the Linq statement and the loop does look ok, but will produce different results than in the `Autocomplete()` method, as you are selecting `Relation.Name` instead of `Relation.Name.ToLowerInvariant()`.

**Refactoring**

As this refactoring is based on the original method we use the `Select()` with `ToLowerInvariant()` first and are checking afterwards if it contains the `searchTerm`

```
public ActionResult AutocompleteSuppliers(string searchTerm)
{
    searchTerm = searchTerm.ToLowerInvariant();

    IEnumerable<string> suppliers = db.Relations
        .Where(l => l.IsSupplier && l.AdministrationId == Helpers.Session.AdministrationId)
        .Select(l => l.Name.ToLowerInvariant())
        .Where(s => s.Contains(searchTerm))
        .OrderBy(s => s)
        .Take(5);

    return Json(suppliers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: I had to tweak it a little to get it to work, but these are some nice suggestions. For some reason, LINQ won't recognize ToLowerInvariant() (it will try to execute it as an extension method), but it does know ToLower().

Comment: For me with .NET 4.0 it is working flawless